# Can't get value entered in popup textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, textbox

I have a popup window which I created using the JQuery UI. It opens when you click on the button Configure:

[image]

When I click on the button random IP, an IP from a list of IPs found in a array appears randomly.
These are the codes for it:

**Codes**

```
/*Random IP generator*/
var textArray = [
    '2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1/48',
    '2001:DB8:C003:1::F00D/48',
    'FEDC:BA98:7654:3210::3/48',
    'FF01::43/48',
    '2FFB:1000:2000:0003::12f0/48',
    '2001:2AC:CAD:0000::/64'
];
var randomNumber = textArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * textArray.length)];

$("#random").click(function () {
    $('#value').val($('#value').val() + randomNumber);
});
```

And this is the form:

**Codes**

```
<div id="dialogbox" title="IPv6 Calculator">
    <form>
        <center><input type="text" placeholder="IPv6 Address and Netmask" id="value" size="25"/></center>

    </form>
    <p>
    <center>
        <button id="calculate" onclick="calculate()"
                style="background-color:#B4BA22; border-radius:3px; cursor:pointer;">Calculate
        </button>
        <button id="random" onclick="random()" style="border-radius:3px; cursor:pointer;">Random IP</button>
    </center>
    </p>
</div>
```

After getting an IP in the textbox, either by entering it manually or using the Random IP button, I need to use this IP for calculation purposes but when I click on the Calculate button I can't get the IP from the textbox. This is the calculate function:

```
$("#calculate").click(function () {
    $("#dialogbox").dialog("close");

    $("#result").dialog("open"); //another popup form opens

    ip = $("#value").val(); //ip declared globally
    $("#result").attr("title", "Result for IP" + ip) //tried to use the value obtained to change the attribute of a textbox but to no avail.
});
```

I still can't get the value from the textbox. Any help please?

**EDIT**

The complete codes: [Liveweave](http://liveweave.com/Of4JCo)

Comment: assign value before close dialog().

Comment: Does dialog close destroy and empty all the content? In that case @Anik is right I think do `val()` before `dialog('close')`. Btw this looks cool! Is it open source somewhere?

Comment: this UI looks like packet tracer ..

Comment: You are binding each click event twice, once using inline script and using jQuery to bind event??? Not sure what are `calculate()` & `random()` methods. BTW, your input is inside a `form` but won't be submited to the server. Not sure what is the purpose of the `form` here?

Comment: Yes this is part of my final year project based on an elearning website for IPv6. :) Thanks, that can be a possibility. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Still doesn't work. :/

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem.  Also note that `<center>` is deprecated in html5

Comment: Liveweave demo has no code in it

Comment: Hi, From the code which have shared I have observed some points. You are calling function on click which are not available in your js and also jquery click functions are also written which is causing conflict in click functions. I tried to replicate your code here's the link ---> http://liveweave.com/zstRRA <---- Let me know if this helps - Help :)

Comment: Thanks @help. I removed the errors you cited but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Check this one ---> http://jsfiddle.net/nvZc4/641/ <---- - Help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code which have shared I have observed some points. You are calling function on click which are not available in your js and also jquery click functions are also written which is causing conflict in click functions.

Here is the replicate for your senario

[Fiddle](http://tinyurl.com/plsjzou)

Help :)

Answer (score 2):

After 30 minutes of reseraching, i came up with perfect and easy solution for your TextBox output.

*** *Minor error in your JQuery code:*

1. For your calculate button, **button id and function has same value** ie. 
   **[calculate]** due to which your function is not calling.
2. You provided **onclick** but it should be [onClick], **"C" must be capital**.

Else, everything is fine.

**** Correction*

1. change [onclick] to [**onClick**].
2. Just make the first letter of your ["calculate()"] as ["**Calculate()**"].

---

> *** Overall solution:

---

Easy JavaScript code for you JQuery Code:
Replace your JQuery code with this JavaScript code :)

==================================================================

```
    <div id="dialogbox" title="IPv6 Calculator">
    <form>
        <center><input type="text" placeholder="IPv6 Address and Netmask"      
         id="value" size="25"/> </center> 
    </form>
    <p>
      <center>
        <button id="calculate" onClick="Calculate()"
                style="background-color:#B4BA22; border-radius:3px; 
                 cursor:pointer;">calculate
        </button>
        <button id="random" onclick="random()" style="border-radius:3px; 
         cursor:pointer;">Random IP</button>
      </center>
    </p>
</div>


<script>
 function Calculate(){
var calc=document.getElementById("value").value;
alert(calc);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. :) I'll try this it does makes sense.

Comment: @Damini  executed the above code on my browser then only posted it here. Hope it will get executed on yours too. For any concern you can reach to us :)